# Equivalent of Bash's $() on Windows?

Tags: windows, bash

On Bash, I can use a subshell to fill the result of one command into the next:

```
$ echo $(sub-command args)
```

and if `$(sub-command args)` wrote `foo` to standard out, then the above command would be equivalent to:

```
$ echo foo
```

Does Windows 7 have a way to do this in `cmd.exe`?

The reason I want to do this is so I can easily run executables from npm's installation directory without having that directory on my path:

```
$ $(npm bin)/grunt build
```

Comment: In what shell on Windows?  Are you running Bash on Windows?  Should work the same as bash anywhere else.  If this isn't bash, then the shell you are using matters.  That is, powershell certainly supports subexpressions, using the exact same syntax even.

Comment: Good point. I meant in `cmd.exe`.

Comment: AFAIK cmd.exe has no support for sub-expressions.

Comment: Yeah, on the latest version of powershell, `echo $(echo foo)` returns `foo`.

Answer (score 8):

as they already stated in the comments, there is no native way of doing this with cmd. However there is a hack that you may use for your case (as `npm bin` only returns one line):

```
for /F "tokens=*" %n IN ('npm bin') DO @(%n\grunt build)
```

or inside a batch file you have to duplicate the `%`:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%n IN ('npm bin') DO @(%%n\grunt build)
```

### Alternatives

#### Batch

You could generate a script that receives the parameter and runs the command, something like

```
:: Takes the parameters and send to npm bin output
for /f "tokens=*" %%n in ('npm bin') do @(%%n\%1 %2 %3 %4 %5)
```

Save it as npmbin.cmd in your path, then you could run:

```
npmbin.cmd grunt build
```

#### Powershell

For your case, you should be able to invoke it through powershell using the invoke-expression cmdlet:

```
iex "$(npm bin)\grunt build"
```

I don't have npm on me right now, but I tested with other program and it looks like it would work.

#### Environment Variable

Anyway, I think the previous are very complicated "solutions", while you only want to simplify your command. I was wondering if you could create a global variable, say `NPMBIN` and then use it for your commands:

```
%NPMBIN%\grunt build
```

To extend this you could set up a task to set it programatically for your user (or eventually the computer) using `setx`, some batch like:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%n in ('npm bin') do @(setx NPMBIN %%n)
```

Hope it helps. Regards